# How to convert two characters to one using sed

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I need to change two characters (`\t\n`) for only one (`\t`).
All lines ending in Tab will join with the next line.

I used this command:

```
sed -i 's/\t\n/\t/g' file.txt
```

but it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '1h;1!H;$!d;x;s/\t\n/\t/g' file
```

Sed is line based and uses the `\n` to delimit what it presents in its pattern space. The above solution gathers up the entire file into the hold space ( a spare register) and then does the global substitution returning the desired result.